# javascript print nested object using for loop?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

how do i print out all the person in the person object?

For Example i want my output to be like this.

John Doe 25

Paul Vosper 23

```
 var txt = "";
 var person = {
            p1: {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25},
            p2: {fname:"Paul", lname:"Vosper", age:23}
           }; 
  var x;
  for (x in person) 
  {
    txt += person[x] + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a map/join:

```
var txt = Object.keys(person).map(function(k) {
  var p = person[k];

  return [p.fname, p.lname, p.age].join(' ');
}).join(' ');
```

Output in the console:

[image: output]

If you want a line break element (`<br>`) between them, just join on a `<br>`:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Object.keys(person)
                                            .map(combineAllProperties)
                                            .join('<br>');

function combineAllProperties(k) {
  var p = person[k];

  return [p.fname, p.lname, p.age].join(' ');
}
```

Comment: so the only way to do it is to write a separate function to combine and print it? you cant just iterate an object in an object and print?

Comment: @Mebighobo, you can just iterate and print, but the way I've suggested is a semantic programming paradigm (the algorithm you're trying to implement is fundamentally a map/join, and JavaScript supplies those methods out of the box). It's not a "separate" function, it's a callback to the `map` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Array.prototype.reduce* in conjunction with *Object.keys*:

```js
var person = {
  p1: {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25},
  p2: {fname:"Paul", lname:"Vosper", age:23}
};

document.write(Object.keys(person).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
  var o = person[p];
  return s + (i>0?'<br>':'') + o.fname + ' ' + o.lname + ' ' + o.age
  }, '')
);
```